# Error VBS script property

Tags: vbscript

I changed the properties of a VBS file to run with cmd, but now the "open with" option has gone from the right-click menu.

How can I set it back to windows vbs script?

Answer (score 1):

In the folder, Right mouse click on the file and select properties. In the **Type of file** section, click the **Change** button. Use **Browse** button to select Microsoft Windows Based Script Host (wscript.exe) from C:\Windows\System32

Comment: The main problem is the change button is gone.their is no change option.You can try it by first changing the properties of .vbs file to run on cmd.